# Expresion regular Decimales(Dinamicos) Java

Tags: java, regex

Necesito de su ayuda debido a que tengo una expresión regular para validar que tipo de punto flotante esta recibiendo, esto es porque el separador decimal puede llegar como `.` o `,` no tengo la forma de forzar un solo tipo de separador por lo tanto deseo validarlo por una `regex` y no la he podido terminar, he intentado de varias maneras y no logro obtener el resultado esperado, me pueden orientar por favor.

**Números:**
`171`, `171.00`, `1770`, `1,700`, `1,700.00`, `1,777,777`, `1,777,777.00`, , `1777777.00`

**Expresión Regular**

1. Opción: `String patternString = "^[0-9]{0,3}+|(\\,[0-9]{0,3})+(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$";`
2. Opción: `String patternString = "^[0-9]{0,3}|(\\,[0-9]{0,3})(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$";`
3. Opción: `String patternString = "^[0-9]+(\\,[0-9]{0,})+(\\.[0-9]{0,})?$ | ^[0-9]+(\\,[0-9]{0,})?$";`
4. Opción: `String patternString = "^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{0,})+(\\,[0-9]{0,})?$";`

---

**resultado esperado:**

Para este caso solamente estoy evaluando donde el patron del numero sea `#,##0.00`, para el otro caso creeria que solo seria invertir las `,` por los `.`

**Opcion1:**

- `1.71` - Ok
- `1.71717171` - Ok
- `171` - Ok
- `171.00` - Ok
- `1770` - Ok
- `1,700` - Ok
- `1,700.00` - Ok
- `1,777,777` - Ok
- `1,777,777.00` - Ok
- `1777777.00` - Ok

**Opcion 2:**

- `171,00` - Error(False)
- `1.700,00` - Error(False)
- `1.777.777` - Error(False)
- `1.777.777,00` - Error(False)
- `1777777,00` - Error(False)
- `1,00` - Error(False)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, quieres dos expresiones regulares. Una para que te valide los casos en que el separador de miles sea coma y el de decimales punto y otro para que valide el caso contrario. Cada expresión regular debe admitir sólo los números que encajen con su caso y rechazar los que serían el otro caso.

Entiendo también (más que nada por los ejemplos) que la parte decimal tiene siempre dos decimales tan solo. De no ser así sería imposible distinguir si la cadena `"2,125"` representa dos unidades con 125 centésimas, o bien dosmil ciento veinticinco unidades.

Si entendí correctamente, las expresiones regulares serían:

- Separador de miles con coma y de decimales con punto (demo [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/j3Lvgb/1))

  ```
  ^\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$
  ```
- Separador de miles con punto y de decimales con coma (demo [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/j3Lvgb/2))

  ```
  ^\d{1,3}(\.?\d{3})*(,\d{1,2})?$
  ```

Observa que en ambos casos, si la expresión la vas a meter entre comillas por ser una cadena, debes duplicar cada `\`, aunque esto depende del lenguaje en el que uses la expresión regular.

La idea de estas expresiones es:

- tras el inicio de línea, viene un grupo de 1 a 3 dígitos
- Seguido de cualquier cantidad de grupos de tres dígitos precedidos opcionalmente de coma (o punto en el segundo caso)
- Seguido opcionalmente de un grupo de dos dígitos precedido de punto (o coma en el segundo caso)

Aunque en los casos de prueba que has dado esta expresión funciona correctamente, también dejaría pasar cosas raras, como `11.111111111.111,11` (segundo caso), en las que se pone o se omite arbitrariamente el separador de miles cada tres cifras.

Comment: mil gracias, lo entendiste super bien.